# How can I add Product count for categories?

Tags: product-list

how can I add product count for categories in Magento? I want product count to be placed on sidebar. Tried several ways but failed all the time
Thanks for any help

Comment: I don't have a solution but I don't recommend this. It affects performance.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code, it will give you all the active categories(except root category) and its products count.

```
$categories = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addIsActiveFilter()
    ->addFieldToFilter('level', array('neq' => '0'));

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo $category->getName() . ' - ' . $category->getProductCount();
    echo'<hr/>';
}
```

Comment: Please don't use `>addAttributeToSelect('*')`, take the time to look up which attributes you need and add those specific fields. Retrieving the whole table just to use 2 values is a waste of resources